# in javascript on button click redirect to current url + text from js function

Tags: javascript

I would like to redirect to the current "url" + "text" returned by Function1 when a button is clicked, in JavaScript:

```
function Function1() {
    return window.location.href + "/search";
}
<button id="myButton" onClick=Function1()> </button>
```

What is a good solution to achieve this?

My attempt doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out. You need to replace/change the current href

```js
function Function1() {
                window.location.href = window.location.href + "/search";
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton" onClick=Function1()> </button>
```

As an added note you can also use `window.location.replace(window.location.href + "/search");`
Which would replace the current page and not keep it in history. i.e. the user cannot go back from to the previous page from the redirected page.

Comment: Thank you Isabel. Works on a separate example. But when I add it inside my project it doesn't redirect. any thoughts if this is to do with https binding or how to best debug?

Comment: I suggest you check out the web developer console and see if there are any errors in the JS. Also it would be a good idea to `console.log(window.location.href + "/search");` just to see what it's returning.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
function Function1() {
    window.location.href = window.location.href + "/search";
}
```

I hope this will help you.